# Cannot make calls in Microsoft Lync 2010 app

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread

Device: Sony X10a
Android: 2.3.3

Can the [Microsoft Lync 2010](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.lync) app on the play store make calls?

I can login to my office365 lync account and send messages, but the phone icon is greyed out.

Is voice not avilable on Android, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Lync 2010 has support for calls:

> Lync 2010 for Android extends the power of Lync to your mobile device
>   – including rich presence, instant messaging, **audio conferencing**, and
>   **calling features** from a single, easy-to-use interface.

However, you will need to check with your IT Department if it has been enabled for your account.

Comment: Is there anyway to enter the server details? We have a msft live.com account which doesn't get picked up automatically

Comment: @Martin Beckett Sure, there is Advanced Options in the log-in screen. You need to talk to IT support (if this is a corporate account) if audio is enabled, and how to configure your Lync.